# Alert message while hiding a particular row on table during scrolling using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am working on one sample application. In this application I drag and drop the database tables. If that tables had any primary and foreign link on another tables means that was automatically generate the link to that particular table.

I have a problem that means that tables had the `overflow:auto` so that the div had scrollbar. While I am scrolling means that the link was going to top of the form. How to stop that?

my sample code is as follows

```
$("#tbl" + $(ui.draggable).attr('id') + " tr").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {

        var Source = $(ui.draggable).attr('id').substring(0, $(ui.draggable).attr('id').length - 1);

        var Target = $(this).attr('id').substring(0, $(this).attr('id').length - 1);

        if (Source.substr(0, 3) != 'div' && Target.substr(0, 3) != 'div' && Source != Target) {
            if (Source.substr(0, 2) == 'tr' && Target.substr(0, 2) == 'tr') {
                var connection = jsPlumb.connect({
                    connector: ["Flowchart", { stub: 20}],
                    source: $(ui.draggable),
                    target: $(this),
                    anchor: ["TopRight", "RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle"],
                    paintStyle: {
                        strokeStyle: "blue",
                        lineWidth: 3
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of your code? And what does an alert message have to do with a mispositioned link?

Comment: @LittleBigBot added sample code mate please review it

Comment: the problem is, when it reaches the top of the page, you have to notify a message, or stop that behavior, right?